# How do I know the script options in a npm package?

Tags: npm, command-line-arguments, tailwind-css

For example, I installed tailwind CSS via npm by npm init && npm install tailwindcss. After that, I make a script in package.json like `"build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css"`(I just copy-paste it from stuckoverflow). Now focus on **-o**, how a developer knows there is a -o option available for tailwind. I checked node-module/tailwindcss/script/build.js but there is no such thing that I currently understand( I mean, I found 0 clue). Pls give light on it. Do we have some standardization or unwritten rule that creator of npm package follow?

Answer (score 2):

The `scripts` field in your `package.json` defines commands that are run with `npm run` in the context of npm. This allows you to use the command-line interface that are provided by different npm packages, without installing them globally. Many of these CLIs also expose a `--help` flag, or a `help` command.

To run the CLI from a npm package not installed globally, you may need to use [`npx`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx). In your case, you can run:

```
npx tailwindcss
```

which tells you that there is a `help` command that gives you more information.

```
$ npx tailwindcss                                                                                                                                            
  
   tailwindcss 2.1.2
  
   Usage:
      tailwind <command> [options]
  
   Commands:
      help [command]            More information about the command.
      init [file]               Creates Tailwind config file. Default: tailwind.config.js
      build <file> [options]    Compiles Tailwind CSS file.
```

If you are comfortable reading the source code in your `node_modules` folder, you can also find more information about these commands and the code that runs. To find where the CLI is defined, you can check `node_modules/tailwindcss/package.json`, which defines a `bin` key. In this case, it shows that the `tailwindcss` command comes from `lib/cli.js`. While the code is transformed, you can poke around and find `lib/cli/commands/build.js`, which contains the options for the `build` command.

```js
const options = [{
  usage: '-o, --output <file>',
  description: 'Output file.'
}, {
  usage: '-c, --config <file>',
  description: 'Tailwind config file.'
}, {
  usage: '--no-autoprefixer',
  description: "Don't add vendor prefixes using autoprefixer."
}];
```

If the package is open source, you may be able to find the original, untransformed source online. In Tailwind's case, they have a [Github repo](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss) where you can view [the raw source for the build command](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/cli/commands/build.js).